# How do we get the date to the last Friday of the month when the last day of the month falls on a weekend

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

How do we get the date of the last Friday  of the month when the last day of the month falls on a weekend for example in may 2020 the last friday of the month is 29.

```
 Example input : may 2020

    output : may 29 2020 , since the last day of may which is 31 falls on weekend

        Example input : june 2020
output : june 30, 2020 , since the last day of june does not fall on weekend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the day number from the last day of the month.If friday(dayno =5) falls out of 5 then subtract by 5, else add 2 . Then finally subtract the days from the last day of the month if day number is 0 or 6, else return the last day of the month.

```js
var calc = function(monthYear) {
    var lastDay = moment(monthYear, "MM-YYYY").endOf("month");
    var lastDayNumber = lastDay.day();
    var daystoSubtract;
    daystoSubtract =
        lastDay.day() >= 5 ?
        (daystoSubtract = lastDayNumber - 5) :
        (daystoSubtract = lastDayNumber + 2);
    if (lastDay.day() === 0 || lastDay.day() === 6) {
        return lastDay.subtract(daystoSubtract, "days");
    } else {
        return lastDay;
    }
};

console.log(calc("05-2020").format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
console.log(calc("06-2020").format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: bro I think there is a problem when the logic  , " only when the last day of the month falls on a weekend. , how about if we try june 2020 ? the date should be june 30 right ? isntead of Jun 26, 2020

Comment: you specifically asked for last friday if I am not wrong

Comment: @MarkLuthberg Check now

Comment: @vr12 , I think this would be cleaner sir if we use moment js

Comment: this uses moment js itself

Answer (score 0):

My vanilla javascript version.

```js
function getVen(_month, _year) {
 
  // Add 1 month for count down on current "_month"
  _year = _month == 12 ? _year + 1 : _year; 
  _month = _month == 12 ? 1 : _month + 1;
  
  // Set Date
 var d = new Date(_month + '/01/' + _year);
  // Remove 1 day
  d.setDate(d.getDate()-1); // Last day of "_month/_year"
  
  // If last day not Saturday nor Sunday
  if (d.getDay() != 6 && d.getDay() != 0) return d;
  
  // Count down looking for day "5"=Friday
 for (var i=7; i>0; i--) {
   if (d.getDay() == 5) return d;
    d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);
  }
  
  return ''; // Not found ? 
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = getVen(05,2020) + '<br/>';
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += getVen(06,2020);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: @MarkLuthberg I hope I understood.